# Django-avatar ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am using django-avatar in my website (Django 1.4). However, today I got this error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 94-100: ordinal not in range(128)`

Here is the full error log: http://dpaste.com/755691/

Any ideas what might that be, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it encounters a character problem when looking up the avatar file. So you may have a user which has a profile image with a "weird" character in its filename. Have you checked the value of the variable `path` ? You may need to convert the filename so it does not contain characters from foreign languages.

Comment: Thank you, I am looking at it right now. I can't find anything "weird". Is there something I could do to django-avatar in order to be friendlier with "weird" characters?

Comment: You are right that was the problem. There was one avatar with non-latin characters.